# Search until next character with sed and regex

Tags: regex, unix, batch-file

I got an image with an URL like:

`<img alt="" src="http://www.example-site.com/folder_with_underscore/folder-with-dash/3635/0/235/NumBerS_and_Uc/image.png" />`

I'm using `sed "s///g"`

So what I'm trying is to replace the src value but this is most of the time totally different.

Is there a way to use `sed "s/src=\" (until first " ) / new url /g"`

**Extra info:**

I'm using Cygwin on Windows
and `PATH=C:\cygwin\bin` in my .bat file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[^"]` will match any charater apart from `"`, so you can use:

```
 sed 's/src="[^"]*"/src="NEWURL"/g'
```

Example:

```
[me@home]$ echo '<img alt="" src="http://www.example-site.com/folder_with_underscore/folder-with-dash/3635/0/235/NumBerS_and_Uc/image.png" />' | sed 's/src="[^"]*"/src="http:\/\/stackoverflow.com"/g'
<img alt="" src="http://stackoverflow.com" />
```

Note that that will match till the **first** occurence of `"` which is probably what you want. If you really want to match till the **last** occurence of `"`, you could simply do:

```
 sed 's/src=".*"/src="NEWURL"/g'
```

The regex is greedy and so will take up as many charactes as possibly, thus matching till the last occurence of `"`. While this will also work in the example above, it will not behave as expected if there are other contents within your input that also contain `"`.

Comment: Thnx, that works in the Terminal... So in a batch file it would be something like:

sed 's/src="[^"]*"/src="http:\/\/stackoverflow.com"/g' input.txt > output.txt

Comment: C:\xxxxxx>echo ' alt=""
 src="http://www.example-site.com/folder_with_underscore/folder-with-dash/3635/0
/235/NumBerS_and_Uc/image.png" /  0<img 1>'  | sed 's/src="[^"]*"/src="http:\/\/
stackoverflow.com"/g'
The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn's solution is mostly correct, but it does not deal with the case in which a newline appears in the src url.  `sed` is really not very good at dealing with such cases, but you can hack a solution:

```
sed '/src/{
/src="[^"]*"/{ s//src="NEWURL"/; n; }
s/src=".*$/src="NEWURL"/
p
:a
s/.*//;
N
/"/!ba
s/[^"]*"//
}
' input
```

Note that many of the newlines above are superfluous in some versions of sed, but necessary in others. (In particular, the newline after `:a` and after the branch command, as some versions of sed will terminate the label only at the newline.  I believe that versions of sed which allow a label to terminate with a semi-colon are not strictly compliant with the standard, but it is a common practice.)  This script does the simple replacement where appropriate, but if a quote is not found following `src="`, it enters a loop deleting lines until a terminating `"` is seen.  This is an ugly solution, and I recommend against using sed for parsing xml.

Comment: Thnx for the extra info, I'll use that if there are newlines in my src urls (+1)